# Is there any way to refresh Kendo-grid in angular?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have tried everything under earth to have the kendo-gird to have a refresh in Angular environment without having to cause a page refresh:

I have following code in my controller:

```
$scope.$on('import-grid-loaded', function (event, args) {
            alert('hello');
            portabilityService.portList($
                $scope.importGridOptions = {
                    dataSource:
                        {
                            data: new kendo.data.ObservableArray($scope.portDetails),
                            pageSize: 10
                        },
                    sortable: {
                        mode: "multiple",
                        allowUnsort: true
                    },
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true
                    },
                    dataBound: function () {
                        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                    },

                    detailTemplate: $('#Details').html(),

                    columns: [
                         {
                             field: "FileName",
                             title: "File Name",
                             width: "120px"
                         },
                         {
                             field: "RequestedByUseraname",
                             title: "Imported By",
                             width: "120px"
                         },

                          {
                              field: "CreatedOn",
                              title: "Imported On",
                              width: "120px",
                              type: "date",
                              format: "{0:dd MMM yyyy} at {0:h:mm tt }"
                          },
                        {
                            field: "StateString",
                            title: "State",
                            width: "120px",
                            encoded: true,
                            template: '#=GetFaClass(data.StateString)#'
                        }
                    ]
                };

            });
        });
```

My HTMl looks like

```
<div id="importGrid"ng-if="portDetails" class="row table-condensed table-frame grid" kendo-grid k-options={{importGridOptions}} k-rebind={{portDetails}}></div>
```

1. This code makes sure that $scope.PortDetails do exist before the first load
2. Also loads the Grid successfully in the first load
3. Now, I want the grid to refresh when Portdetails are updated. That's why I broadcast an event so that it re-runs the code above in my controller and I was hoping that it will re bind the grid. But nothing happens

I have also tried other ways like JQuery

```
$('#importGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(data);
    $('#importGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    $('#importGrid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

That also does not work. Is there any simple way to refresh kendo grid in Angular after datasource is updated?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing wrong to refresh the grid. I think the way you're creating your data is wrong. When you set the dataSource's data to a new ObservableArray based on your array of data, you create a copy of it, like a snapshot, so it won't change anymore. If you want to change grid's data, you'll have to change it directly in the dataSource's data. So changes in `$scope.portDetails` won't take effect, which it is probably what you're doing, relying on `$scope.portDetails` for data.

In [this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EjUFU) you have two grids, the second one is initialized like yours, the first one is what I think you have to do:

```
dataSource: {
    transport: {
        read: function(options) {
             options.success(new kendo.data.ObservableArray($scope.portDetails));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that first grid receives new data when you add it and refreshes, but the second one doesnt. The code above will make sure it will always create a new ObservableArray of the current state of `$scope.portDetails` everytime dataSource reads new data.